# Equivalent of Rails' seed file in Django with Python3

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, seed

I would like to manually populate the database in my Django app.
In Rails, I just have to enter the info in the seed file and that's it.
The db.sqlite3 file has many numbers in it which I don't get.

I am a beginner so please forgive my ignorance. In which directory should I put my DB and which format should the file be in? Then, how can I manually (no Faker I want to write the instances myself) create the DB? Finally, how can I retrieve the info to display it in my view?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate Django database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024510/populate-django-database)

Comment: Its not the same thing. I would like to write the instances myself without any faker. I would just like to know how to create a file where I can do that and then how to display the info in my view